# How do i do the following using LINQ feature of C#?

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

I need help with the following statement to be converted to lambda statement how do i do it?

```
for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++)
    {
        gList.Add(new G(this, new L(row, column), 0, 20, 30));
    }
}
```

thanks for all the help!!!

Comment: I do hope `G` and `L` are substitutes for the real class-names?

Comment: Based on what it looks like you want, you may want to edit the title/tags to include "LINQ" as opposed to "lambda".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<G> gList = Enumerable.Range(0, rows)
    .SelectMany(row => Enumerable.Range(0, columns)
        .Select(col => new G(this, new L(row, col), 0, 20, 30)))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I should make myself more familiar with SelectMany! :-)

Comment: It is a correct answer to the Q. But in this particular situation I don't find LINQ much of an improvement (readability) over for(;;).

Answer (score 2):

```
var gList = Enumerable.Range(0, rows)
    .SelectMany(row =>
        Enumerable.Range(0, columns)
            .Select(column => new G(this, new L(row, column), 0, 20, 30)
        )
    ).ToList() or .ToArray();
```

SelectMany will flatten the Enumerable returned from the Select into an IEnumerable.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that this results in an IEnumerable<G> (I believe) on which you'd probably call `ToList()` and assign to `gList`...

Comment: Also might be good to call `gList.AddRange` because the OP makes no indication that `gList` is an empty list.

Comment: @Davy8 that goes beyond the scope of the question - I'm not coding for them just answering the question. :P

Comment: while the OP should be able to figure that out, it isn't 100% answering the question because it isn't functionally equivalent in all cases.  I still +1 but thought it worth at least noting.

Answer (score 2):

```
var gList = from row in Enumerable.Range(0, rows)
            from col in Enumerable.Range(0, columns)
            select new G(this, new L(row, col), 0, 20, 30)
```

My favourite for inline cartesians like this

Comment: Does this preserve the same order as the original? (not saying it doesn't, I'm honestly curious)

Answer (score 1):

Give me the indexes, project each index to a new `L`, project each `L` to a new `G` and assign the resulting sequence of objects to a list named `gList`.

```
var indexes = from row in Enumerable.Range(0, rows)
              from column in Enumerable.Range(0, columns)
              select new { Row = row, Column = column };
var ls = indexes.Select(index => new L(index.Row, index.Column));
var gs = ls.Select(l => new G(this, l, 0, 20, 30)).ToList();
var gList = gs.ToList();
```

Note that if `gList` is an existing list that you want to add to you can replace the last line by

```
gList.AddRange(gs);
```

It reads exactly like what it is doing.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the other answers, using lambdas don't always result in cleaner code.  Unless you have a specific reason for using lambdas in this case, I would leave the for loops as is.

Readability should be your primary concern, but I imagine using a normal `for` loop might be slightly faster because you don't have the overhead of function calls, but the difference in most cases won't matter.

Comment: If this execution construct is central to the app, it might become a performance concern using the LINQ approaches. I do think it is less error prone in [this syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736415/how-do-i-do-the-following-using-lambda-feature-of-c/5736527#5736527)

Answer (score 0):

Putting everything into one single expression would lead to terrible code. Why would you do that? Does the following help: (untested, out of my head)

```
public IEnumerable<L> GenerateLs(int rows, int columns)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++)
        {
            yield return new L(row, column);
        }
    }
}

gList.Add(l => GenerateLs(rows,columns).Select(new G(this,l,0,20,30)));
```

Comment: +1 for unexpected hybrid. It won't compile (misplaced `l => `), but it does use a lambda. I think this one is arguably the best advice